# Calculate sum without duplicates in DAX power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image: Table]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty5wu.png)

I want to calculate  (A-UP + A-UPUP + B-UP)
Where state and tier are filter values used in slicer which changes according to selection.

I want sum of unique Y values according to state and tier.

In dax any idea?

Comment: For the table above; "Distinct Y value for UP" means 100 or 500?

Comment: A-UP - 100,
A- UPUP - 200,
B - UP - 300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Please test this:

```
Distinct_Y_SUMMATION =
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE ( YourTable, YourTable[state], YourTable[tier], YourTable[Y] ),
    [Y]
)
```

The Screenshot of the code if we run & test it:

[image: Distinct_Y_Summation]

Extra Bonus:

If you want to see the table, just create "New Table" command and paste this code:

```
Distinct_Y_Table =
SUMMARIZE ( YourTable, YourTable[state], YourTable[tier], YourTable[Y] )
```

The screenshot of the above code:

[image: GGH]

Answer (score 1):

```
SUMX(
    SUMMARIZE(
         ALLSELECTED(tbl)
        ,tbl[state]
        ,tbl[country]
        ,tbl[tier]
    )
    ,CALCULATE(Average(tbl[Y]))
)
```

Comment: I have updated the question, can you please check

Comment: did you try the second measure?

Comment: yes. didnt work

Comment: Try it now. If it will be not that result please let me know what  the measure returns